# Flutter Only valid value is 0: 1 If i remove the 'value':

Tags: flutter, dart

I am simply splitting the values of string but it's showing the error

My code

```
List<Map<String, String>> divideString(String wording) {
  final policies = wording.split('|').where((w) => w != '');
  var displayData = <Map<String, String>>[];
  policies.forEach((policy) {
    final splited = policy.split('=');
    final displayPolicy = <String, String>{
      'name': splited[0],
      'value': splited[1]
    };
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
  });

  return displayData;
}
```

if I remove 'value': splited[1] its working fine I think in some places 'value': splited[1] is empty so maybe its showing error?

String something looks like this

```
I/flutter (14910): INPATIENT & DAYCARE||||||||||PRE-AUTHORIZATION=MANDATORY AT NON-PANEL HOSPITALS|||||HOSPITAL NETWORK=220+ FACILITIES NATIONWIDE|||||EMERGENCY HOTLINE NOS.=ROUND THE CLOCK|||||ACCIDENTAL EMERGENCIES=25% ENHANCEMENT IN AVAILABLE INPATIENT LIMITS|||||PRE-HOSPITALIZATION=30 DAYS BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION|||||POST-HOSPITALIZATION=30 DAYS AFTER HOSPITALIZATION|||||DAYCARE PROCEDURES=UNLIMITED|||||ICU CONFINEMENT=UNLIMITED|||||DENTAL TREATMENT=WHEN REQD. DUE TO ACCIDENT FOR PAIN RELIEF ONLY|||||LOCAL AMBULANCE=TO AND BETWEEN HOSPITALS|||||CATARACT SURGERY=COVERED WITH STANDARD FOLDABLE LENS ONLY|||||SPECIALIZED INVESTIGATIONS=COVERED e.g., CT Scan, MRI, ECHO etc.|||||VACCINATIONS=1ST DOSE COVERED AT BIRTH|||||MATERNITY BENEFITS||||||||||PRE / POST NATAL EXPENSES=10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS|||||CIRCUMCISION BENEFIT=10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS|||||DELIVERY BY MIDWIFE PKR.5000/-|||||SPECIAL BENEFITS||||||||||HEPATITIS TREATMENT=COVERED|||||CONGENITAL CONDITIONS=NOT COVERED|||||PRE EXISTI
```

What I am doing is break the line when this symbol shows "|" and split it when "=" symbol show but the issue is somewhere = sign isn't available

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
List<Map<String, String>> divideString(String wording) {
  List<String> policies = wording.split('|');
  List<Map<String, String>> displayData = [];
  policies.forEach((policy) {
    final List<String> splited = policy.split('=');

    // If an '=' sign is present, the length will be == 2
    if(splited.length == 2){
     final displayPolicy = <String, String>{
      'name': splited[0],
      'value': splited[1]
      };
      displayData.add(displayPolicy);
    }
  });
  
  print('======= output, line by line =======');
  displayData.forEach((item) => print(item));
  print('\n');

  print('======= returned data, unformatted =======');
  print(displayData);
  return displayData;
}
```

Output:

```
======= output, line by line =======
{name: PRE-AUTHORIZATION, value: MANDATORY AT NON-PANEL HOSPITALS}
{name: HOSPITAL NETWORK, value: 220+ FACILITIES NATIONWIDE}
{name: EMERGENCY HOTLINE NOS., value: ROUND THE CLOCK}
{name: ACCIDENTAL EMERGENCIES, value: 25% ENHANCEMENT IN AVAILABLE INPATIENT LIMITS}
{name: PRE-HOSPITALIZATION, value: 30 DAYS BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION}
{name: POST-HOSPITALIZATION, value: 30 DAYS AFTER HOSPITALIZATION}
{name: DAYCARE PROCEDURES, value: UNLIMITED}
{name: ICU CONFINEMENT, value: UNLIMITED}
{name: DENTAL TREATMENT, value: WHEN REQD. DUE TO ACCIDENT FOR PAIN RELIEF ONLY}
{name: LOCAL AMBULANCE, value: TO AND BETWEEN HOSPITALS}
{name: CATARACT SURGERY, value: COVERED WITH STANDARD FOLDABLE LENS ONLY}
{name: SPECIALIZED INVESTIGATIONS, value: COVERED e.g., CT Scan, MRI, ECHO etc.}
{name: VACCINATIONS, value: 1ST DOSE COVERED AT BIRTH}
{name: PRE / POST NATAL EXPENSES, value: 10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS}
{name: CIRCUMCISION BENEFIT, value: 10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS}
{name: HEPATITIS TREATMENT, value: COVERED}
{name: CONGENITAL CONDITIONS, value: NOT COVERED}


======= returned data, unformatted =======
[{name: PRE-AUTHORIZATION, value: MANDATORY AT NON-PANEL HOSPITALS}, {name: HOSPITAL NETWORK, value: 220+ FACILITIES NATIONWIDE}, {name: EMERGENCY HOTLINE NOS., value: ROUND THE CLOCK}, {name: ACCIDENTAL EMERGENCIES, value: 25% ENHANCEMENT IN AVAILABLE INPATIENT LIMITS}, {name: PRE-HOSPITALIZATION, value: 30 DAYS BEFORE HOSPITALIZATION}, {name: POST-HOSPITALIZATION, value: 30 DAYS AFTER HOSPITALIZATION}, {name: DAYCARE PROCEDURES, value: UNLIMITED}, {name: ICU CONFINEMENT, value: UNLIMITED}, {name: DENTAL TREATMENT, value: WHEN REQD. DUE TO ACCIDENT FOR PAIN RELIEF ONLY}, {name: LOCAL AMBULANCE, value: TO AND BETWEEN HOSPITALS}, {name: CATARACT SURGERY, value: COVERED WITH STANDARD FOLDABLE LENS ONLY}, {name: SPECIALIZED INVESTIGATIONS, value: COVERED e.g., CT Scan, MRI, ECHO etc.}, {name: VACCINATIONS, value: 1ST DOSE COVERED AT BIRTH}, {name: PRE / POST NATAL EXPENSES, value: 10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS}, {name: CIRCUMCISION BENEFIT, value: 10% OF MAT. or PKR 2,000/- WHICHEVER IS LESS}, {name: HEPATITIS TREATMENT, value: COVERED}, {name: CONGENITAL CONDITIONS, value: NOT COVERED}]
```

Comment: This appears to be a useful contribution, but it'd be even more useful if it contained an explanation of your approach, and what the most relevant calls are. Would you mind _editing_ your answer to provide that information for future readers?

Answer (score 0):

modifiy your code like this to see where the problem is.

```
List<Map<String, String>> divideString(String wording) {
  final policies = wording.split('|').where((w) => w != '');
  var displayData = <Map<String, String>>[];
  policies.forEach((policy) {
    if(policy.contains('=')){
      final splited = policy.split('=');
    final displayPolicy = <String, String>{
      'name': splited[0],
      'value': splited[1]
    };
    displayData.add(displayPolicy);
    }else{
      print('no suitable data in ' + policy);
    }
    
  });

  return displayData;
}
```